# In VSCode, Cordova Tools cannot access the Ionic live reload server with EADDRNOTAVAIL error when launching an android emulator

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

I'm developing an app with Ionic3 by using VSCode in which cordova-tools is installed.

I want to use "ionic live reload".

When I select "Run Android on emulator" and clicked the run button, the following error occurs.

> [cordova-tools] Error processing "launch": Error in the Ionic live
>   reload server: Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available
>   fe80::1:8100 at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2]
>   (net.js:1273:19) at listenInCluster (net.js:1338:12) at doListen
>   (net.js:1469:7) at process.internalTickCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19) code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL', errno:
>   'EADDRNOTAVAIL', syscall: 'listen', address: 'fe80::1', port: 8100 }

How can I solve this? Any ideas?

I've already tried:

- change "devServerPort" in launch.json to random ones
- change "devServerAddress" in launch.json to "localhost", "127.0.0.1" and "fe80::1"
- kill all the node processes by the command "killall node"

but nothing solved.

When I changed the server address to random one, the error massage changed to make me enter a valid address.

When I killed node processes, I ensured the processes are killed by the command "ps aux | grep node" and Activity Monitor.

---

This is my launch.json about the android emulator.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    ...
        {
            "name": "Run Android on emulator",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "target": "emulator",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "ionicLiveReload": true,
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "todo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.7",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.19",
    "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.3.1",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.10",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.11",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-local-notification": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

My environments

- macOS Mojave version 10.14.2
- Ionic CLI version 4.8.0
- Visual Studio Code version 1.30.2
- Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
- Android Studio version 3.2.1